# Handling Connections in Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, slick

My code uses Slick 3.0. It has as a common `db` object.

```
object Common {

  private [database] val db = Database.forURL(
    url      = // read from config,
    user     = // read from config,
    password = // read from config
  )

}
```

Then, in my database services `object`'s, my methods look like:

```
private lazy val myTableQuery = TableQuery[MyTable]

def getTableObjects: Future[Seq[MyTableObject]] = {
  val action = myTableQuery.result
  Common.db.run(action)
}
```

where I'm re-using the `Common.db` throughout multiple services.

In Slick 3.0, what's the idiomatic way to run a DB call?

I saw in the Slick 2.0 [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/connection.html) that an implicit `session` can be used.

However, I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct in Slick 3.0.

Comment: I think we're having the same issue, that the db is instantiated for every service (and hence loads of connection pools). Perhaps that's not your issue. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no longer need an implicit session.

Currently mobile, check out the sample chapters of essential slick -http://underscore.io/training/courses/essential-slick/

It shows how to do it now.

I am one of the authors.

Jono